# Azure Stream Analytics job degraded with no runtime errors

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

problem:

all of a sudden Stream Analytics job marked as "Degraded". No runtime errors, no service health warnings, no alerts at all. **It worked fine so far.** Now, zero output events with "Degraded" warning with no causes.

details:

- input: IotHub (serialization format: JSON)
- output: SQL Server database
- used SQL query with TumblingWindow (60 minutes) to aggregate data from sensors (worked fine so far; no errors or warnings; table scheme has't changed)
- Resource Health: always "Available"
- no other job in the same Consumer Group

**EDIT:**

this is SQL we use in the ASA job:

```
WITH multisensordata AS
(
SELECT 
  multidata.ArrayValue AS singledata,
  GetMetadataPropertyValue(event, 'IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId') AS device
FROM
  [iothub] as event
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.message.mm) AS multidata
)
SELECT
  CAST(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,'1970-01-01', System.Timestamp()) AS bigint) AS aggregationTimestamp,
  multisensordata.device AS device_id,
  singlesensordata.ArrayValue.dk AS data_key,
  AVG(singlesensordata.ArrayValue.v) AS avg_value,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) OVER (ORDER BY singlesensordata.ArrayValue.v) AS median_value,
  uda.NSAMPLE(singlesensordata.ArrayValue.v) AS nValue
INTO
  [sql-database]
FROM
  multisensordata
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(singledata.sm) AS singlesensordata
GROUP BY multisensordata.device, singlesensordata.ArrayValue.dk, TumblingWindow(minute, 60)
```

SOLUTION:

It turned out that ASA had major bug: I used UDA that sometimes were receiving null values. This was the cause of 'Degraded' status and no output action. Azure has fixed this issue. Fix hasn't been deployed to all regions, due to Covid-19 problems.

Comment: It's hard to help you with such information.We don't have any idea of your actual sql query ,data format, diagnostic log etc...Otherwise,if you make sure you did everything right,you could submit feedback to ASA team for official help which is more efficient.

Comment: Feedback already submitted. I hoped that someone had encountered similar problem and have some neat advice.

Comment: Have you enabled diagnostic logs for you Stream Analytics job? If not, enabling that and using Log Analytics will make it easy to parse through the most recent logs to find out any issues your job might be running into. Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-job-diagnostic-logs#send-diagnostics-to-azure-monitor-logs

Comment: Hey @MacKarczewski, if the answer to this question is on the comments can you please post it so others can learn? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question with solution/explanation.

Comment: Thanks :). Can you also add it as an Answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that ASA had major bug: I used UDA that sometimes were receiving null values. This was the cause of 'Degraded' status and no output action. Azure has fixed this issue. Fix hasn't been deployed to all regions, due to Covid-19 problems.